# showing laravel auth errors on different tabs of bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have implemented Laravel Auth in bootstrap modal and bootstrap modal have 2 tabs, one is for login and one is for registration.

On registration tab: 
Users registered through unique username and email, and i want to show errors on the registration tab when email or username is already exist after clicking the signup button. it's showing me that error but that error shows up on the login tab and not on the registration tab.

here is my code:

```
<div class="modal-tab-section wd-modal-tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs wd-modal-tab-menu text-center" role="tablist">
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" id="login-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#login" role="tab" aria-controls="login" aria-expanded="true">Prihlásiť sa</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="sign-up-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#sign-up" role="tab" aria-controls="sign-up">Zaregistrovať sa</a>
     </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
     <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="login" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="login-tab">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 p0 brand-description-area">

              <div class="brand-description">
                 <div class="brand-logo">
                    <img src="{{URL::asset('assets/img/DEALSON-LOGO1.png')}}" style="width: 25em;" alt="Logo">
                 </div>

              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 p0">
              <div class="login-section text-center">
                 <div class="social-media">
                    <a href="{{ url('/auth/facebook') }}" class="facebook-bg"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> Prihlásiť sa</a>

                    <a href="{{ url('/auth/google') }}" class="google-bg"><i class="fa fa" aria-hidden="true"></i>Google Prihlásiť sa</a>
                 </div>
                 <div class="login-form text-left">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                       @csrf
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="email">Email</label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Johnmist@gmail.com |">
                          @if ($errors->has('email'))
                          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                             <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                          </span>
                          @endif
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="password">Heslo</label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" id="password" name="password" placeholder="*********">
                          @if ($errors->has('password'))
                          <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                             <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                          </span>
                          @endif
                       </div>
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary wd-login-btn">Prihlásiť sa</button>
                       <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                 {{ __('Zabudol som heslo?') }}
             </a>
                       <div class="form-check">
                          <label class="form-check-label">
                             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                             Uložiť heslo
                          </label>
                       </div>
                       <div class="wd-policy">
                          <p>
                             Pokračovaním. Potvrdzujem, že som si prečítal a pochopil<a href="{{'/policy.html'}}"> podmienky používania a zásady ochrany osobných údajov</a> . Nemáte účet? <a href="{{'/register'}}" class="black-color"><strong><u>Prihlásiť sa</u></strong></a>
                          </p>
                       </div>
                    </form>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="tab-pane fade" id="sign-up" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="sign-up-tab">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-6 p0 brand-login-section">

              <div class="brand-description">
                 <div class="brand-logo">
                    <img src="{{URL::asset('assets/img/DEALSON-LOGO1.png')}}" style="width: 25em;" alt="Logo">
                 </div>

              </div>
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-6 p0">
              <div class="sign-up-section text-center">
                 <div class="login-form text-left">
                    <form method="POST" action="/register">
                       @csrf
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="email">Email</label>
                          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="username">Užívateľské meno</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="John Smith" name="username">
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="password">Heslo</label>
                          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="*********" name="password">
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-check">
                          <label class="form-check-label">
                             <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="subscribe">
                             Odoberať novinky
                          </label>
                       </div>
                       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary wd-login-btn">Zaregistrovať sa</button>
                       <div class="wd-policy">
                          <p>

                          </p>
                       </div>
                    </form>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

errors are showing up when laravel check it in the register controller after validation.

**Prihlásiť sa means LOGIN**

**Zaregistrovať sa means Registration**

[image: here] is the image of the login/signup modal

[image: here] is the error which i want on the other tab which is registration tab:

Answer (score 1):

You can use Named Error Bags for this.

from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#named-error-bags):

> If you have multiple forms on a single page, you may wish to name the
>   MessageBag of errors, allowing you to retrieve the error messages for
>   a specific form. Pass a name as the second argument to withErrors:

```
return redirect('register')->withErrors($validator, 'login');
```

> You may then access the named MessageBag instance from the $errors
>   variable:

```
{{ $errors->login->first('email') }}
```

After adding the error bags you can display the correct tab with something like this:

```
<div id="login"
     class="tab-pane fade @if($errors->register->isEmpty()) show active @endif">
...
</div>

<div id="register"
     class="tab-pane fade @if(! $errors->register->isEmpty()) show active @endif">
...
</div>
```

Comment: how can i show the register tab error on register tab, it's actually showing on login tab and i want to show it on register tab when it redirects back from register controller after validation.

Comment: @NaveedAli did you add the error bags for login and register?

Comment: errors are working fine with me, and it is showing error, but bootstrap modal is opening the login tab by default and the register tab errors are showing up on login tab.

Comment: @NaveedAli errors are not working fine unless you add the error bags, because you will not know if the error came from the login or register form. After adding the error bags you then can check which form has an error and show the right tab.

Comment: you can see the error on the second image, it's coming from the named error bags but this error is for the register tab and not for login tab. i want to show up register tab by default after validating the fields in the register controller.

Comment: public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
                        ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }

Comment: this is the register method, how can i add the redirect route along with error message bag?